# getJSON help jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

so i know this bit of code works

```
$.getJSON('data/book.json', function(jd) {

         $('#stage').html('<p> id: ' + jd.data.productTypeList[0].id + '</p>');
         $('#stage').append('<p>name : ' + jd.data.productTypeList[0].name+ '</p>');
         $('#stage').append('<p> longName: ' + jd.data.productTypeList[0].longName+ '</p>');

});
```

the problem is i am trying to update it to here and getting an error

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/book.json")
          .success(function(data, status, xhr) { 
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
              //create book for each item and then insert into the collection
              tmpItem=new Book({id:item.data.productTypeList[0].id,category:item.data.productTypeList[0].name,name:item.data.productTypeList[0].longName});
              self.add(tmpItem);
            });
            //dispatch customized event
            self.trigger("fetchCompleted:Books");
          })
          .error(function() { alert("error"); })
          .complete(function() {
                console.log("fetch complete + " + this);
          });
      }
```

but i cant get this to work and keep getting an error of item.data is undefined.

once i have sorted that i plan on changing the 0 to i an so that it will pick up all the results in the array

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(item)`? Maybe that way you can see why it is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!('productTypeList' in data)) {
    //catch illegal response 
}
$.each(data.productTypeList, function(i,item){
    //create book for each item and then insert into the collection
    tmpItem=new Book({id:item[i].id,category:item[i].name,name:item[i].longName});
    self.add(tmpItem);
});
```

Comment: console.log(item) says its undefined and the other bit of code didnt work either

I have put it here..  http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/getJsonTest/index2.html

strange..

Comment: Edited my answer, got one 'data' to much, but MarcoK beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `$.each` is wrong.

1. You each over the data, not the items in the data.
2. You ask the "item" again inside the each, which isn't available.

Try this:

```
$.each(data.productTypeList, function(i, productType){
    // Use "productType" here, example:
    // new Book( { id: productType.id } )
}
```

Comment: Thank you MarcoK .. its been a long day,,

Comment: No problem, glad to help you out. If this was the solution for your problem, could you mark it as such?

Comment: i can only mark it when i get an extra 4 points.. still a newbie and stuck on 11.. will mark it as soon as i get the extra 4 points :)

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on the line containing item.data in your favorite browser console.

While there, look at the data, i, and item variables and make sure they contain what you expect.

It should be quite easy to determine what's wrong and fix it at that point.